# Idiomatic Haskell way of termination recursion in this functoin

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

What is the more haskellish way to stop the recursion of this function? Currently I'm using a nested if/else, and returning an empty list if the next combination "overflows".

```
nextcomb [] []     = []
nextcomb lst maxes | length lst == length maxes = 
let lastel = last lst
in if    lastel < last maxes
   then (init lst) ++ [lastel+1]
   else let higherbit = (nextcomb (init lst) (init maxes)) 
        in if   higherbit == [] 
           then []
           else higherbit ++ [1]
nextcomb lst maxes | otherwise = []
```

To clarify, what it does is it takes a list of numbers like [1,1,1,1] and increments it like:

[1,1,1,1] -> [1,1,1,2]

...

[1,1,1,9] -> [1,1,2,1]

...

[1,1,9,9] -> [1,2,1,1]

etc.

BUT, the second argument is a list that indicates the maxmum value for each column. So if the maxes were [2,3], and the initial list was [1,1], then the progression woudld be:

[1,1] -> [1,2]

[1,2] -> [1,3]

[1,3] -> [2,1]

[2,1] -> [2,2]

[2,2] -> [2,3]

[2,3] -> []

---

Edit: "Little Endian" version as recommended by chepner

```
nextcomb' [] [] = []
nextcomb' lst maxes | length lst /= length maxes = []
nextcomb' lst maxes =
    let firstel = head lst
    in if    firstel < head maxes
       then (firstel+1) : (tail lst)
       else let higherbit = (nextcomb' (tail lst) (tail maxes))
            in if   higherbit == []
               then []
               else 1 : higherbit
```

Comment: Note that it's probably easier to work with reversed, "low-endian" lists, and only display them as "big-endian".

Comment: Noted, good catch. thanks.

Comment: Why in your last example the last digit can't be 4 but the first digit can be 2?

Comment: that was an error, fixed.

Comment: You may enjoy reading this: http://conal.net/blog/posts/adding-numbers

Answer (score 3):

You should make illegal states **unrepresentable**

So, instead of using two lists, use a list of tuples. For example, the first  value in each tuple could be the maximum, the second one the actual value.

This also simplifies the logic dramatically, as the errors "maxes too long" and "maxes too short" can not happen.

Comment: Keeping them separate has its benefits, too. If you swap `lst` and `maxes` (or just use `flip nextcomb`), you can define things like `binary8bit = nextcomb (take 8 repeat 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` expression is simply hiding the real base case, which is that if *either* argument is empty, return the empty list.

```
nextcomb [] [] = []
nextcomb lst maxes | length lst != length maxes = []
nextcomb lst maxes = let lastel = last lst
                     in if    lastel < last maxes
                        then (init lst) ++ [lastel+1]
                        else let higherbit = (nextcomb (init lst) (init maxes)) 
                             in if   higherbit == [] 
                                then []
                                else higherbit ++ [1]
```

I would probably rework the logic like this. (Note, I'm far from a Haskell expert and tend to answer these questions as an exercise for myself :)

```
-- Reversing the arguments and the ultimate return value
-- lets you work with the head of each list, rather than the last
-- element
nextcomb lst maxes = reverse $ nextcomb' (reverse lst) (reverse maxes)
-- The real work. The base case is two empty lists
nextcomb' [] [] = []
-- If one list runs out before the other, it's an error. I think
-- it's faster to check if one argument is empty when the other is not
-- than to check the length of each at each level of recursion.
nextcomb' [] _ = error "maxes too long"
nextcomb' _ [] = error "maxes too short"
-- Otherwise, it's just a matter of handling the least-significant
-- bit correctly. Either abort, increment, or reset and recurse
nextcomb' (x:xs)  (m:ms) | x > m = error "digit too large"
                         | x < m = (x+1):xs  -- just increment
                         | otherwise = 0:(nextcomb' xs ms) -- reset and recurse
```

(Actually, note that `nextcomb' [] _` won't trigger if you don't recurse after the last digit. You could argue that a too-long `maxes` isn't a big deal. I'll leave this unfixed, as the next part handles it correctly.)

Alternately, you could verify the lengths match in the initial call; then you can assume that both will become empty at the same time.

```
nextcomb lst maxes | length lst == length maxes = reverse $ nextcomb' (reverse lst) (reverse maxes)
                   | otherwise = error "length mixmatch"

nextcomb' [] [] = []
nextcomb' (x:xs)  (m:ms) | x > m = error "digit too large"
                         | x < m = (x+1):xs
                         | otherwise = 0:(nextcomb' xs ms)
```

---

Here's an example using `Either` to report errors. I won't vouch for the design other than to say it does type check and run. It's not too different from the previous code; it just uses `<$>` to lift `reverse` and `(0:)` to work with arguments of type `Either String [a]` instead of arguments of type `[a]`.

```
import Control.Applicative
nextcombE lst maxes = reverse <$> nextcombE' (reverse lst) (reverse maxes)

nextcombE' [] [] = Right []
nextcombE' [] _ = Left "maxes too long"
nextcombE' _ [] = Left "maxes too short"
nextcombE' (x:xs) (m:ms) | x > m = Left "digit too large"
                         | x < m = Right ((x+1):xs)
                         | otherwise = (0:) <$> (nextcombE' xs ms)
```

Comment: well maxes and lst do have to be the same length for this logic to be right, so there's slightly more to it than that, but i was talking more about the if then else let in if then else stuff, than about the guards.

Comment: True; I'll put that back as an explicit check.

Comment: Great, thanks. is the nested if in the body of the function itself really idiomatic haskell, or is it better to use Maybe or something?

Comment: You could probably use `Maybe [a]` or `Either String [a]` to indicate a failed update, but I'm not the one to show you an example :)

Answer (score 2):

Please check if next implementation is useful for you, because a more "haskellish" way (at least for me), is using built in recursive functions to achieve the same goal

```
nextcomb [] [] = []
nextcomb lst maxes
  | length lst /= length maxes = []
  | lst == maxes = []
  | otherwise = fst $ foldr f ([],True) $ zip lst maxes
  where
    f (l,m) (acc, mustGrow)
      | mustGrow && l < m  = (l + 1:acc, False)
      | mustGrow = (1:acc, True)
      | otherwise = (l:acc, False)
```

(Edited) If need catch errors then can try this:

```
nextcomb [] _ = Left "Initial is empty"
nextcomb _ [] = Left "Maximus size are empty"
nextcomb lst maxes
  | length lst /= length maxes = Left "List must be same length"
  | lst == maxes = Left "Initial already reach the limit given by Maximus"
  | otherwise = Right $ fst $ foldr f ([],True) $ zip lst maxes
  where
    f (l,m) (acc, mustGrow)
      | mustGrow && l < m  = (l + 1:acc, False)
      | mustGrow = (1:acc, True)
      | otherwise = (l:acc, False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's draw a diagram!  I'm going to make slightly different assumptions than the initial problem:

1. A little-endian representation like chepner suggested;
2. Instead of inclusive maximum values, I'm going to go with exclusive **bases** to make things more similar to addition-with-carry.
3. I'm going to use digits in the range `[0, base)`.

Here's the diagram:

```
 digits = [d0, d1, ..., dn]
 bases  = [b0, b1, ..., bn]
 --------------------------
 result = [r0, r1, ..., rn]
```

Now we can ask: for each digit `ri` of the result, what does its value depend on?  Well, these things:

1. The value of `di`
2. The value of `bi`
3. Whether the previous `r` resulted in a carry

So we can write this as a function:

```
import Control.Monad.State  -- gonna use this a bit later

type Base = Int
type Digit = Int
type Carry = Bool

-- | Increment a single digit, given all the contextual information.
singleDigit' :: Base -> Digit -> Carry -> (Digit, Carry)
singleDigit' base digit carry = (digit', carry')
    where sum = digit + if carry then 1 else 0
          digit' = if sum < base then sum else sum - base
          carry' = base <= sum
```

Note that I took care to make sure that the `singleDigit'` function's type ends with `Carry -> (Digit, Carry)`.  This is because that fits the `state -> (result, state)` pattern that is typical of the state monad:

```
-- | Wrap the `singleDigit'` function into the state monad.
singleDigit :: Base -> Digit -> State Carry Digit
singleDigit base digit = state (singleDigit' base digit)
```

Now with that we can write the following function:

```
increment :: [Base] -> [Digit] -> [Digit]
increment bases digits = evalState (sequence steps) True
    where steps :: [State Carry Digit]
          steps = zipWith singleDigit bases digits
```

What we're doing here is:

1. Using `zipWith` to "sew" the bases and digits list together on corresponding elements.  The elements of this list correspond to the individual `steps` of the computation.
2. Using `sequence :: [State Carry Digit] -> State Carry [Digit]` to chain all the individual steps into one big step that passes the intermediate `Carry` state around.
3. Feeding `True` as the initial `Carry` input to that big chain of steps (which causes the chain to increment).

Example invocation:

```
>>> take 20 (iterate (increment [3,4,5,10]) [0,0,0,0])
[[0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[2,0,0,0]
,[0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[2,1,0,0]
,[0,2,0,0],[1,2,0,0],[2,2,0,0]
,[0,3,0,0],[1,3,0,0],[2,3,0,0]
,[0,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0],[2,0,1,0]
,[0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0],[2,1,1,0]
,[0,2,1,0],[1,2,1,0]
]
```

The lessons I'd stress:

1. Break problems into smaller pieces.  Don't try solve too much in one function!  In this case, the trick was to split off the solution for single digits into its own function.
2. It pays very much to think carefully about the *data flow* in a problem: what information is needed at each step of the problem?  In this case, the diagram helped reason that out, which led to the `singleDigit'` function.
3. One of the big ideas of functional programming is to separate the "shape" of the computation from its "content".  In this case, the "content" is the `singleDigit` operation, and the "shape" of the computation—how to combine the individual steps into a big solution—is provided by the `State` monad and the `sequence` operation.
4. I did not write a single recursive function; instead, I made ample use of library functions like `zipWith`, `sequence`, `take` and `iterate`.  You ask for a more idiomatic Haskell solution, so well, here goes: complicated recursive functions definitions are not as idiomatic as using library functions that encapsulate common recursive patterns.
5. This hopefully will encourage you to study monads some more.  There are many, many problems out there where, if you express them in terms of one of the standard monads like `State`, you can reuse generic functions like `sequence` to solve them very easily.  It's a tall learning curve but the results are worth it!